# is scaling in SVM always necessary?

Tags: r, svm

I've already read some posts here about SVM scaling and why it is so important. Now I'm wondering if scaling in the `ksvm` function is always necessary if my data are already normalized. I have a RPKM dataset, already normalized with the `log2` function:  miRNA on columns (features) samples on rows (tumoral vs normal samples), a very small dataset (22 samples, 11 normal and 11 tumoral).
For some features, the value is unvarying for the majority of samples selected (I'm performing a cv-10), so I get a warning from the SVM function saying that scaling is not possible, I think that could be a variance problem, but if I set `scaled=FALSE` I can fix the warning. Do I need do scaling anyway?

Comment: Can you link to the posts you've read? If the values for a particular feature don't vary in the data set, is there a reason not to just throw them out ... ?

Comment: I mean, there's some variation in a few of the features i.e. just like one or two different values in 22 samples.. cross fold validation select sonly few of them for each fold, so some folds will have for example no variation for that specific feature. I think I have to remove features whit low variance (nearZeroVar from caret could help?) Anyway I've just red this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225344/why-feature-scaling-in-svm but if someone can clarify me this aspect, it will be great, thank you

Comment: Thank you so much, having such a little amount of samples could be problematic I think.

Comment: how many features?

Comment: 1023 features and 22 samples

Comment: Using **any** classification algorithm on so few samples with that many features is almost certainly bound to fail. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality#Machine_Learning